# Netbeans: How do I copy remote connections from one computer to another?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, connection

I work on 2 different Windows 10 PC's.  I have my Netbeans projects set up on my NAS so I can share all the projects.  However, how do I copy my remote connections from one machine to the other so I don't have to set up SFTP/FTP for each and every project on my 2nd machine?
Is there a config file somewhere I can copy over?

Answer (score 0):

Windows:
C:\Users[windowsUsername]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections

Ensure Hidden Folders/files are set to visible